# Propogating Standard Error through monte carlo?

Tags: monte-carlo, error-propagation

I have a model that has a bunch of parameters that I experimentally determined the mean and accompanying standard error/STD.  Because the model has some tricky terms in it I'd like to propagate the error using a monte carlo approach.  What I can't wrap my mind around is how to determine the standard error this way, right now Im sampling parameters from normal distributions with associated standard deviations and get a model output from which Im determining mean and standard deviation but because I arbitrarily set the number of simulations, I can't wrap my head around determining standard error of the model output.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: standard error of what?

Comment: Standard error of the model output

Comment: Hi David Stupski, welcome to CV! You have the start of a good question here. What will improve it is editing (link at lower left) to *include your model*. This will attract folks who may wish to answer, as well as deflect those voting to close because your question (as it currently stands) is unclear.